# Find the second largest date in df python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please advise on how to select the second max date in df rows.

I have a df like this:

```
ID   Count   DDate1  DDate2 DDate3 DDate4 DDate5
```

Columns with `ddate` are converted to datetime.
The max value I have found in this way:

```
cols_1 = df_deal_employee.columns[2:6]
df['max_date'] = df[cols_1].max(1)
```

But can I create a column with the following max date? (second largest).

Comment: What do you mean by "following max date"? The date that comes immediately after the max date?

Comment: @user17242583 Exactly, the following date after max date.

Comment: And you want all the rows of that column to be that same date? Because assigning a single value to a column causes all the rows of that column to be the value.

Comment: @user17242583 I have various columns, so a new column should show the second largest date for EACH row.